# Can you declare variables (specifically line variables) using for loop in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

Is it possible to declare line variables via a loop?

Working on an indicator in which I would like to declare multiple line variables in the form line1, line2 etc based on a number specified by user input but not sure if it is not possible or I just suck at structure and syntax.

Instead of:

```
UInput = input.int(n,"User defined input"....
var line1 = line.new(na,na,na,na
var line2 = line.new(na,na,na,na,......
....
var linen = line.new(na,na,na,na,......
```

As n could be 50 or more would like to do something along the lines of:

```
UInput = input.int(n,"User defined input"....
for i = 0 to (n-1)
   var linei = line.new(na,na,na,na,......
```

I have tried a few variations using "line"+str.tostring(i) but not sure how to return that as line type instead of string type.

Is this doable or is it a case of declaring individually?

Comment: Bonus for whom?

Comment: Please read [ask] first and keep in mind that SO has a Q&A format with one question per post. The questions should be on-topic, clear and on focus

Comment: Apologies, just thought as it followed on from the original it was more of a one in the same but appreciate this is not the way so edited down to one question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. You just need to declare an array of lines and push each new line in your loop into your array.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, the second part of the post mentioned trying to create an array of line type with incremental names using a loop, which I was also couldn't do, in order to achieve the above but I was asked to remove it as it breaches the How to Ask format. I will create a second post I guess.